# How to make request and send response on the network?

Tags: json, request, response

I am working on a JSON project and I basically want to hit on some specified URL with some request and get the response back. I want to know if there are some sites available that can provide me help for request, response on JSON?

Any sort of help is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Back when "Ajax" was being coined (and well before), we often used the XML HTTP Request object ([W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)) but web development is more mature now. Libraries such as jQuery wrap this functionality for easy use ([jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/))